# C MPI Pipeline using insertion sort

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, insertion-sort

I am trying to implement using this technique: [http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs572/pipelinedsort.pdf](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ejan/mcs572/pipelinedsort.pdf)

Therefore, the program works and sorts elements when arraySize = numberOfProcessors. The problem is that I need to implement an algorithm, which would divide the array into subLists and the master would be able to send subList to the slave to sort it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <time.h>    // time()
#define WORKTAG 1  /* WORKTAG for sending a number */

void Compare_And_Swap(int duomenuBlokas[], int proc_Nr, int step, int *maxValue, int *gottenValue, int sizeOfSublist);
void Collect_And_Sort (int proc_Nr, int sizeOfArray, int maxValue, int *sortedArray);

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int processNumber; // current process number : 0 - Master
   int * sortingArray; // Our sorting array
   int * subList; // sublist
   int tempValue;
   int maxValue;
   int numberOfProcessors; // On how many processors we run our program
   MPI_Status status;
   MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
   int arraySize = atoi(argv[1]); // Aray size input through the console
   int sizeOfSublist;
   subList = (int*)calloc(arraySize,sizeof(int));
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numberOfProcessors);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&processNumber);
   if(processNumber==0) /* Master generates p random numbers */
   {
      sortingArray = (int*)calloc(arraySize,sizeof(int));
      srand(time(NULL));
      for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
      {
          sortingArray[i] = rand() % 100;
      }
      printf("The %d numbers to sort : ",arraySize);
      for(int i =0; i<arraySize; i++)
      {
          printf(" %d", sortingArray[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");
      fflush(stdout);
   }
       sizeOfSublist = arraySize / numberOfProcessors; // Get the size of each subList
       subList = (int*)calloc(sizeOfSublist,sizeof(int));
       MPI_Scatter(sortingArray, sizeOfSublist, MPI_INT, subList, // Get sublists
        sizeOfSublist, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   for(int i=0; i<numberOfProcessors-processNumber; i++)
   {
      if(processNumber==0) // Master gets the value
      {
         tempValue = sortingArray[i]; // Send subLists here [21,32] for example
         printf("Master gets %d.\n",sortingArray[i]);
         fflush(stdout);

         Compare_And_Swap(subList,processNumber,i,&maxValue,&tempValue, sizeOfSublist); // Masteris siunc
      }
      else // Slave receives the value
      {
         MPI_Recv(&tempValue,1,MPI_INT,processNumber-1,WORKTAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
         printf("Slave %d receives %d.\n",processNumber,tempValue);
         fflush(stdout);
         Compare_And_Swap(subList,processNumber,i,&maxValue,&tempValue, sizeOfSublist);
      }
   }
   Collect_And_Sort(processNumber,arraySize,maxValue,subList); // Collect values


    printf("Exit. \n");
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

void Compare_And_Swap(int duomenuBlokas[], int proc_Nr, int step, int *maxValue, int *gottenValue, int sizeOfSublist) // Parallel pipe-sort function
{

   if(step==0) // assign maxValue
   {
       *maxValue = *gottenValue;
   }

   else
      if(*gottenValue > *maxValue)  // Send maxValue
      {
         MPI_Send(maxValue,1,MPI_INT ,proc_Nr+1,WORKTAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         printf("Slave %d sends %d to %d.\n",proc_Nr,*maxValue,proc_Nr+1);
         fflush(stdout);
         *maxValue = *gottenValue;

      }
      else // Send gotten value
      {
         MPI_Send(gottenValue,1,MPI_INT,proc_Nr+1,WORKTAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         printf("Slave %d sends %d to %d.\n",proc_Nr,*gottenValue,proc_Nr+1);
         fflush(stdout);
      }
}

 void Collect_And_Sort(int proc_Nr, int sizeOfArray, int maxValue, int *sortedArray)
{
   MPI_Status status;

   if(proc_Nr==0)
   {
      sortedArray[0] = maxValue;
      for(int i=1; i<sizeOfArray; i++)
      {
         MPI_Recv(&sortedArray[i],1,MPI_INT,i,WORKTAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
      }
      printf("Sorted array: ");
      for(int i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++)
      {
        printf(" %d",sortedArray[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   else
   {
        MPI_Send(&maxValue,1,MPI_INT,0,WORKTAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }

}
```

I used MPI_Scatter to get the sublists and I am thinking that I should send them in this place: tempValue = sortingArray[i] replace with something tmpArray = subList; The problem I encountered is that all the values are the same because "MASTER" processID - 0 contains only the first subList. For example array[2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and after MPI_Scatter "MASTER" sends only [2,3] everytime. Thank you a lot.

If needed, I can also attach the result pictures to make it more clear. Let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MPI_Scatterv` in general. Your approach will work if all the sublists have the same length.

The bigger problem is that your test `if(*gottenValue > *maxValue)` needs to become much more complicated because your `gottenValue` will be an array, so you need to compare each component. You could for instance in each communicating pair: let both processes receive from the other and keep only the lowest/highest set of elememts.

Comment: Thank you very much, since there is not a lot of information on the internet on this specific topic, it is hard to come up with a solution. However, I'll try my best to compare each component and implement this algorithm with subLists.

Comment: You don't need information about this. It's a matter of elementary programming. Two processes each have an array, now they need to exchange information so that each winds up with half the elements, and the elements on one are all smaller than all the elements on the other.